# UICollectionView dynamic height and width

Tags: objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm Trying to achieve this layout with dynamic height and width

is it possible to achieve this layout?

[image: dynamic uicollection layout]

Comment: I would use stackviews for this, with autolayout

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass for this, which is not really going to be easy.

[This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) and [this](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/) tutorial are a pretty good starting point.